# How to split the array keyword value separated by commas in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, keyword

I have an array in $_POST:

```
Array ( [tags] => Javascript,PHP,Java,C++,Python)
```

How can i convert this Array into Array like this:

```
Array ( [tag1] => Javascript [tag2] => PHP [tag3] => Java [tag4] => C++ [tag5] => Python)
```

I guess i need to use regexp to remove the commas and do split in "foreach as".. But i'm so newbie in PHP... Please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, MooGeek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tags = explode(",", $_POST['tags']);
print_r($tags);
```

Outputs

```
Array (
  [0] => Javascript
  [1] => PHP
  [2] => Java
  [3] => C++
  [4] => Python
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It does the thing! :)

Comment: Btw, it's better to use quotes for accessing array's element, `$_POST['tags']`. Read the documentation, why it is bad write something like `$_POST[tags]`.

Answer (score 1):

For a string with comma, you can split it using explode

`$new_array = explode(',', $_POST['tags']);`

Then you can use the `$new_array` for your process.